# Is PostgreSQL 9.0 JDBC driver working well with 64 bit java?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, x86-64, slackware

I've been struggling with getting James Mail Server to work with PostgreSQL on a 64bit Slackware 13.1.
Are there any known problems with the driver under 64 bit linux and 64bit java ?

I have the same server running fine on a 32bit Slackware again with PostgreSQL 9.0.

Does anybody know what may be the problem?

Edit: Some more details around this problem...
When I stop james mail server via ./bin/phoenix stop I get this in the logs:

```
James Mail Server 2.3.2
Remote Manager Service started plain:4555
POP3 Service started plain:110
SMTP Service started plain:25
NNTP Service started plain:119
FetchMail Disabled
JVM exiting abnormally. Shutting down Phoenix.
 org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component named "thread-manager" failed to pass through the Destruction stage. (Reason: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException).
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.fail(LifecycleHelper.java:354)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.shutdown(LifecycleHelper.java:288)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.shutdown(DefaultApplication.java:566)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.doRunPhase(DefaultApplication.java:482)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.runPhase(DefaultApplication.java:409)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.stop(DefaultApplication.java:233)
at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.stop(ContainerUtil.java:292)
at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.shutdown(ContainerUtil.java:66)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.shutdown(DefaultKernel.java:346)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.kernel.DefaultKernel.removeApplication(DefaultKernel.java:455)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.deployer.DefaultDeployer.undeploy(DefaultDeployer.java:244)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.deployer.DefaultDeployer.dispose(DefaultDeployer.java:154)
at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.dispose(ContainerUtil.java:306)
at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.shutdown(ContainerUtil.java:67)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.shutdownComponents(DefaultEmbeddor.java:598)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.embeddor.DefaultEmbeddor.dispose(DefaultEmbeddor.java:342)
at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.dispose(ContainerUtil.java:306)
at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.shutdown(ContainerUtil.java:67)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.shutdown(CLIMain.java:326)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.CLIMain.forceShutdown(CLIMain.java:295)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.frontends.ShutdownHook.run(CLIMain.java:386)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy(ThreadGroup.java:754)
at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.thread.impl.DefaultThreadPool.dispose(DefaultThreadPool.java:76)
at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.dispose(ContainerUtil.java:306)
at org.apache.avalon.cornerstone.blocks.threads.AbstractThreadManager.dispose(AbstractThreadManager.java:69)
at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.dispose(ContainerUtil.java:306)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.shutdown(LifecycleHelper.java:274)
... 19 more
STOPPED Sun Feb 13 00:01:37 EET 2011
```

When I start the server everything starts great, the logs say james has added file and db repositories but it doesn't create the tables in the database. If it creates the tables it doesn't insert anything inside. I'm sure the user/pass I've set are right and the user can write to the database (tested manually).
I'm using 9.0-801 JDBC 4 and jdk1.6.0_23x64.

Hope this helps for solving the problem.

Comment: You need to include more details.  What issues are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: Why should this be a PostgreSQL driver issue?

Comment: @jzd details were added :) ; @Daniel - I don't know. It just isn't working for a reason and I'm trying to get what it is..

Comment: FYI, there is a new [next-generation JDBC driver](http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/) being re-written from scratch to support only the latest versions of Postgres and Java. You could try that just to see if there is a difference in behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostgreSQL JDBC driver is written in pure Java, so it wouldn't even know the difference between a 32-bit and a 64-bit platform.  It's unlikely that that's the problem; the driver is very widely used on 64-bit hosts.

Comment: I thought that too but ... apparently there is a problem that I can't see where it comes from :/

Answer (score 0):

Peter answered on topic question.

About your stacktrace:
The root cause is *java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException* exception, which thrown only in following cases:

```
if (destroyed || (nthreads > 0)) {
    throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
}
```

it means you already destroyed it or not really stopped.

I see pool is disposed twice in excalibur. It means you will have such message after stop always.